# Smoke+Fire Simulation Fire Not Rendering

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've googled endlessly regarding this issue and can't seem to figure it out. I made sure that all my nodes were set up to emit both smoke and fire, and I have selected the correct option under Flow settings. It shows up in the viewport fine, but only renders the smoke as you can see.[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Color* output of the *flame* attribute isn't what you need. Instead connect the *Fac* output to the ramp. The Fac contains data about the flame intensity, and connecting it to the ramp, will define the color based on the intensity.

Moreover, your intensity multiplier is set quite low. This is not an error, but it may get you very low visibility on the flames.

This image shows the defaults that get set when using *Object* -> *Quick Effects* -> *Quick Smoke*

[image]